# can i use sqlite in developing firefox Os applications instead of IndexedDb?

Tags: firefox-os

Can I use sq-lite in developing Firefox Os applications instead of Indexed Db? I am trying to create a Firefox OS application. I have no more idea about it.

Comment: nope firefox doesnt like sqlite.

Comment: I mean Mozilla didnt want the websql spec,you'll never get a sql db api in any of the Mozilla products.

Answer (score 0):

No. Only webkit-based browsers support Web SQL.  And there isn't a shim to use the Web SQL API on IndexedDB browsers, nor is there ever likely to be.

Although IndexedDB isn't supported on any version of Safari, there is a shim allowing you to use the IndexedDB API on Web SQL browsers. (Abeit I couldn't get it to work.)  So, an IndexedDB solution should be portable to other modern environments.

http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDBShim/

Answer (score 0):

There is not SQLlite support on Firefox OS: you need to use [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB)